# Creating an image and text upload page for user

Tags: php, html, mysql, file-upload, image-uploading

I am after some guidance, how do I produce a text and image upload page for the user to obviously upload an image and text into a set template for other users to see? Do I HAVE to use mySQL or is there a pure PHP alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need MySQL specifically. Any server-side technology that can store data on the server (such as PHP) will do. What is practical and suitable is a different issue, and really depends.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for answering but could you tell me how to do it just with php? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you want something permanent, then you will need MySQL to store the information uploaded by the users.

If you want something semi-permanent, you could look into memcache, but I doubt that's what you want to do because a server reboot would wipe it all.

And you will obviously need PHP to handle the information and communicate with the DB.